# Match one row with another in R and writing results to another file

Tags: r

i have file like this

```
Ind   M1  M2    M3   M4   M5
P1   AA   -/-    GG   CC   TT
P2   TT    AA  GG   TT    CC
1     TT    GG  CC   AA    GG
2     GG   CC   TT   GG   CC
3     AA    TT   GG  CC   TT
4     CC    GG  TT   AA   CC
5      GG   CC  AA   CC   TT
```

i want to check whether P1 and P2 match for M1 or not, if they match that column should be selected and write in outfile, like this i want to continue for remaining columns till M5. I am new to R and tried with nested for loop but unable to get it. It is very easy in excel but the problem is i have more than 44k columns in my data. if R reduced them to below 16000 then i can work in excel itself for my further analysis. can any one help me in this regard? any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to store the column of M1 if they match with P1 and P2, if this is the case I would do like this:

```
tmp <- matrix(rep(1,20),nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
tmp <- setNames(tmp, letters[1:5])

names_int <- c("a","b", "c")


output <- sapply(names_int, function(x){
if(identical(tmp[[x]], tmp[["d"]]) & identical(tmp[[x]], tmp[["e"]])){
return(tmp[[x]])
}})
```

where "d" and "e" would be your P1 and P2 and the names_int are the names of the variable that you want to match

Comment: Hi Michele Thanks lot for your help, https://www.dropbox.com/s/ft943u7rf6v9j4b/row%20match.xlsx?dl=0 I uploaded my data and explanation file there in excel file. you really helped

Comment: Hi,   Sorry for my late reply! I would like to understand a little bit more because apparently, I did not answer correctly before. The thing is that I see in your data that you have selected the column M4 that only matches with P1 and not column M3 that also only matches with P1, therefore I did not understand how I should make the selection. If you explain to me that I am more than willing to help!

Comment: Hi Michele Thanks lot for your help, I am sorry i missed small word but it confused you lot,  First:i want to check whether P1 and P2 match each other for M1 or not, if they not matched(like P1=A/A,P2=T/T)that column should be selected and write in outfile, like this i want to do for remaining columns till M5
2nd step: Now in outputfile I want to match M1 value of 1st individual to P2, if it match then 1 otherwise it will be 0, M1 value is between them like (A/T ) then it will be H and so on for M4 and M5
3rd step:Then I will sum all the 1's and H's
I hope  this time i explained well enough